# Cron jobs not running for specific php files

Tags: php, cron

I have two PHP cron jobs running. In one cron job, am trying to open a file and write some data into it which works fine.

But in the other file, I have added an error_log() statement which is not getting printed into the log file. But the error_log file is getting updated when i manually run this php file. What could be the problem here that it doesn't write to the error_log.txt file only for cron job cases. 
[Note:  The error_log.txt gets updated when i run the php file manually ]

Working cron:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('/home/victor/public_html/victor_php/test/test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, '    Cron test job   ');
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Not Working cron:

```
<?php

error_log("Cron1 test job",0);

?>
```

Comment: without code, it really is impossible to even guess

Comment: updated the code above

Comment: How do you know it's not running?

Comment: please create one test table and insert data in test table for tesing

Comment: Which user runs crontab? root or apache?

Comment: Permissions is my first thought, on the command line you could have access, but maybe cron does not.  See what user cron runs under and then login as that user and see if it works.  Otherwise it's like comparing apples to oranges when using different users.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that the error_log given in my cron job was logging into the error_log of root directory. When we run the php file manually the logs get logged into the error_log file in the current directory, and this is not the case with cron jobs. That was the confusion.

Thank you all for the support guys.